# can labels be turned off in PDFThumbnailView?

Tags: macos, quartz-graphics, pdfview

MacOS provides a very handy set of classes and objects for displaying PDF documents.

PDFThumbnailView is what's used to display a scrolling collection of thumbnails representing each page of the PDF document managed in a PDFDocument (and visible in a full size PDFView, sitting to the right of my PDFThumbnailView).  This is what my UI (with its PDFThumbnailView and PDFView) looks like:

[image: MyPDFThumbnailView]

And here's my question which regards PDFThumbnailView labels (I've circled three of them in the graphic below):

PDFThumbnailView provides a [handy method to change the font of the thumbnail label](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/PDFThumbnailView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PDFThumbnailView/setLabelFont:); but is there a way to actually customize what appears in those labels, or better yet, simply turn that label off completely?

Answer (score 1):

Well, since this question earned me the "tumbleweed" badge on StackOverflow, I might as well answer this question with the (*very non-optimal*) solution that I ended up doing, in case one or two other souls out there ever run into this problem.

[PDFThumbnailView has a "`setLabelFont:`" method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/PDFThumbnailView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PDFThumbnailView/setLabelFont%3a), to which you can assign an extremely tiny font (think 1 point or less).

Yes, that means sharp-eyed users will see a pixel of something underneath each page.

As far as I can tell, there's no way to set a font color (i.e. clear color, gray color matching the background) for that font.

I've filed a Radar enhancement request ( rdar://12631489 ) with Apple to ask them to provide an API to turn off these labels, but I have no idea if they'll actually act favorably on this.